# Heroku starts Thin but returns error from weBrick - Devise User Create Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, thin, webrick

When a new user registration is attempted I receive a server status code of 500 and no error is logged in Heroku. Here is the received response header:

```
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  728
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Mon, 15 Apr 2013 16:43:30 GMT
Server  WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-07-09)
X-Runtime   0.390617
```

There is a Procfile that specifies thin and Heroku starts up fine:

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

Also in my gemfile I specify ruby '1.9.3'

Start up Log

```
2013-04-15T16:37:49.739237+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -p 39185`
(... Removed 3 warning - DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins!)
2013-04-15T16:37:55.104773+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Using rack adapter
2013-04-15T16:37:55.104773+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-04-15T16:37:57.202991+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
2013-04-15T16:37:57.202991+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2013-04-15T16:37:57.202991+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:39185, CTRL+C to stop
2013-04-15T16:37:57.931278+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

It's not just devise that is failing. Any call to any page that is not static fails. Also the response header for any static page has Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-07-09).

What additional configuration items am I missing or should I validate.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of your Gemfile? Also, did you create the app recently or is it an older application? The output of `heroku stack` would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I figured it out. The browser bookmark url was pointing at the wrong application in a different account. Now that my code and browser are pointing at the same thing all makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The browser bookmark was pointing at some old version in an account that is unknown to me. It was just a silly little dash in the application name. Now the project and my browser and the client's browser are all pointing at the same project.